# Shell Script to remove lines of text in a text file

Tags: android, bash, shell, sh

How can I remove a line of text in a file if it exists?

So far I am guessing

```
#!/sbin/sh

mount -o remount,rw /system;

# Make a backup first
cp /system/build.prop /system/build.prop.bak;

# Append
if [ grep -o 'wifi.supplicant_scan_interval' <<</system.build.prop > 1 ]; then
    echo "YO";
fi;

mount -o remount,ro /system;
```

however, this shows me `YO` no matter of it is > 1 or < 1   (it does exist in the file), so this part seems wrong, also, I don't know how I could remove the line?

Can you help?

## Code Update

```
#!/sbin/sh
mount -o remount,rw /system;

function check_prop(){
    busybox grep $1 /system/build.prop;
    return $?;
}

# Make a backup first
cp /system/build.prop /system/build.prop.bak;

echo $(check_prop 'wifi.supplicant_scan_interval');

# Append
if [ $(check_prop 'wifi.supplicant_scan_interval') > 1 ]; then
    # Do my stuff here?
    echo 'YO';
fi;

mount -o remount,ro /system;
```

is returning me a blank line, and `YO`.  If I change it to < 1 it does the same thing

Comment: If you are trying to grep the file `/system/build.prop` (note the typo in your question), you shouldn't be using the `<<<` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/wifi.supplicant_scan_interval/d' inputfile
```

would remove lines matching `wifi.supplicant_scan_interval`

eg

```
$cat input 
hello
world 
hai
$sed '/world/d' input 
hello
hai
```

if you want to delete line from file use `-i` option which is does the action `inplace`

```
sed -i '/wifi.supplicant_scan_interval/d' inputfile
```

EDIT

using `grep` to print all lines except the lines that match the patter.

```
grep -v 'wifi.supplicant_scan_interval' inputfile
```

eg

```
$ grep -v 'world' input 
hello
hai
```

the `-v` option does the negation.

Comment: but is sed available in busybox on android?  (yes it is apparently....)  But I also need to check if it exists 1st because there are other things I need to do in addition to removing the line

Comment: @Kevin you can also use `grep` see the edit. Hope it helps :)

Comment: aye.  saw that, but i still need to check if it exists first

Comment: I havent really gotten the chance to look at this and test yet so excuse me for now... does this (grep) remove the line, or only the text it finds?

Comment: @Kevin it removes the entire line from the output, but it does not edit the file

Comment: Does sed remove it from the file?

Comment: @Kevin yeah `sed -i` will remove from file